# Finding Data from a Json Array Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I have JSON data that is structured like this

```
[
    {
        "cs": [
            {
                "dr": "(i) Two passes at 'A' level in Biology /Zoology /Botany and any other Science subject. (ii)   NCE   at   merit pass       level       in Biology    and    any other            Science subject. (iii) NCE merit pass level in Agriculture (Double Major).",
                "ur": "Five SSCE credits or equivalent             in English    Language, Chemistry, Biology/Agricultural Science., Mathematics     and another      relevant subject.",
                "us": "Any  three  subjects  from Chemistry,              Biology, Agriculture,            Physics, Economics,       Geography and Mathematics.",
                "dc": "BAUCHI accepts: (a) NCE (pass with 5 years teaching experience. (b) N.D at merit pass/lower credit in Biology/Agricultural Science and any other Science subject. (c) Two 'A' Level passes in Biology /Zoology/Botany/Agricultural Science and any other Science subject.",
                "uc": "BAUCHI requires Five 'O' level credit passes in English, Mathematics, Arithmetic, Biology, Agricultural Science, Chemistry or General Science and any two subjects. It accepts credit pass in Arithmetic, or General Science or Technical Trades in lieu of Mathematics, or Biology or Physics respectively. UTME SUBJECTS:|BAUCHI requires Mathematics, Biology/Agricultural Science and any other subject.",
                "_n": "Agricultural Science And Education",
                "_c1": "96",
                "_c2": "81",
                "_c3": "30",
                "_c4": "0",
                "_t": "207"
            }
            ...
        ],
        "_n": "Abubakar Tafawa Balewa University, Bauchi",
        "_no": "55",
        "_c1": "10332",
        "_c2": "632",
        "_c3": "226",
        "_c4": "1",
        "_t": "11191",
        "_own": "FEDERAL",
        "_ab": "BAUCHI",
        "_st": "BAUCHI",
        "_em": "",
        "_pn": "",
        "_ws": "atbu.edu.ng",
        "_ca": "ADAMAWA, BAUCHI, BENUE, BORNO, GOMBE, TARABA, YOBE"
    },
    {
        "cs": [
            {
                "dr": "Two  A' Level passes in Economics, Accountancy, Business Management, Government           and Geography.  Candidate must     have     Science background     at     'O' Level.",
                "ur": "Five SSCE credit passes to include,  English  Language, Mathematics,     Economics and any other two science subjects from Chemistry, Physics,                    Biology, Geography, Health Science, Metal Works, Wood Work, Agric Science, Technical Drawing,  Nutrition  and Food Science.",
                "us": "Mathematics, Economics and any one  of  Chemistry, Physics or Biology.",
                "dc": "BAUCHI accepts: (a) Two 'A' level passes in any of Math, Economics, Commerce, Physics, Chemistry, Bio/Agric. (b) ND/HND at lower credit and above.",
                "uc": "BAUCHI requires five 'O' level credit passes to include English Language, Mathematics, one Science subject and two Commercial subjects.",
                "_n": "Accounting Technology",
                "_c1": "490",
                "_c2": "19",
                "_c3": "8",
                "_c4": "0",
                "_t": "517"
            },
         ...
        ],
        "_n": "University of Lagos",
        "_no": "55",
        "_c1": "10332",
        "_c2": "632",
        "_c3": "226",
        "_c4": "1",
        "_t": "11191",
        "_own": "FEDERAL",
        "_ab": "BAUCHI",
        "_st": "BAUCHI",
        "_em": "",
        "_pn": "",
        "_ws": "unilag.edu.ng",
        "_ca": "ADAMAWA, BAUCHI, BENUE, BORNO, GOMBE, TARABA, YOBE"
    }
    ...
]
```

i want to search the JSON array using the name of the using a course say "Agricultural Science And Education" then it should the university in this case "University of lagos" and "Abubakar Tafawa Balewa University, Bauchi" and the _ur (requirement)

Comment: you should show what you tried

Answer (score 0):

In your example University of lagos doesn't have a Agricultural Science And Education, try this:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(Object.values(arr[i]['cs'][0]).includes('Agricultural Science And Education')){
        console.log(arr[i]['_n'])
    }
}
```